# Subset dataframe by removing records with only one row per hour

Tags: r, gps

I have a data set of GPS locations for a wildlife research project. GPS locations were collected 2x per hour (every 30 mins). However, the GPS collars sometimes would miss a location resulting in 1 location/hour. I need to subset the current data frame to only include locations where I have 2 GPS locations per hour (i.e., remove rows with only one location per hour). My issue is that due to the hierarchical data structure (GPS locations are nested within individual animal ID, Month, Day, Year, and Hour) I cannot find a simple solution to remove rows with only 1 location/hour.

[image: Data Frame Structure--rows in yellow need to be censored (only 1 location/hour)]

I tried a roundabout way using the following code for movement distance (summing the total distance/30-minute location) and it worked great because I could filter out the rows by the "Total" column.

```
net_move<-master_deer%>% group_by(COLLAR_ID,Year,WEEK,Month,Day,Hour) %>% summarise(TOTAL_STEPLENGTH = sum(MOVEMENT_DISTANCE), Total = n())
```

However, I need to use a similar approach for "Net_Displacement" but I can't simply add these numbers. Ideally if there was a way to just censor our those rows with only 1 location per hour and save as a master file that would be ideal.

Comment: It should be easy to do something like `group_by(...) %>% filter(n() > 1)`, which will filter out any combination with 1 row. You have to post some data that have location and your ideal output, otherwise we can help you with filtering your original dataset. But sounds something like `group_by(hour) %>% filter(n_distinct(location) > 1)`.

Comment: @AntoniosK, thanks for the comment! I posted the link above entitled, Data Frame Structure--rows in yellow need to be censored (only 1 location/hour). Does that work?

Comment: I saw that, but you have no location in that dataset! As I said before it will work if you do `master_deer %>% group_by(COLLAR_ID,Year,WEEK,Month,Day,Hour) %>% filter(n() > 1)` on this dataset. Be careful with your column names and the capital/lower case letters.

Comment: @AntonsioK, I've updated the file with generic X,Y, locations. The reason I left it out before was that I cannot publicly share the locations.

Comment: I see that each row has one location, so the above code will work. No need to worry about locations. It's the same as number of locations  = number of rows in the dataset you posted.

Comment: @AntoniosK, yes, that's correct. One location per row (or each row represents a location). I will give the above code a try and reformat the column headings as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Note for others: use package(dplyr) for the code AntoniosK provided.